# Chocolatey fails when installing VS2015 toolset

Tags: visual-c++, azure-devops, chocolatey

I have a Azure pipeline that builds C++ DLLs, I need to build with different toolsets.

I can build 143 (vs2022), 142 (vs2019) and, 141 (vs2017), but when trying to build the 140 (vs2015) version I cannot install the toolset.

I tried the **visualstudio2015professional** package.

I tried the **visualcppbuildtools** (Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 14.0.25420.1)

I tried the **microsoft-visual-cpp-build-tools** (Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 14.0.25420.1)

I'm basing my pipeline on a VS2022 image :

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
 vmImage: 'windows-2022'

steps:


- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Choco install additional packages'
  inputs:
  script: |
    choco install visualstudio2015professional visualstudio2017professional visualstudio2019professional
```

I am missing something obvious ?

I get errors similar to this :

> 2022-02-16T18:07:50.2000629Z WARNING: Generic MSI Error. This is a
> local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself
>
> - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please
>   see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding
>   '--install-arguments="'/l*v
>   c:\VisualStudio2015Professional_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the
>   MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error.
>   2022-02-16T18:07:50.2222631Z ERROR: Running
>   ["C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\VisualStudio2015Professional\2015.03.03\vs_professional.exe"
>   /Quiet /NoRestart /Log
>   C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\vs.log ] was
>   not successful. Exit code was '1603'. Exit code indicates the
>   following: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not
>   an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending
>   reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same
>   version is already installed). Please see MSI log if available. If
>   not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v
>   c:\VisualStudio2015Professional_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the
>   MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error..